# Can I send Curl command result to a Azure DevOps built-in notification email

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that runs a few simple Curl commands  "http_status1=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" URL)" . This will save the status only in http_status1(200, 401, etc) instead of returning the whole curl and it works fine. One of my leads also set an alert notification email that triggers every time the pipeline runs on failure or success which is also fine. My question is this, is there a way to add code or a command in my pipeline script that would include the value of http_status1 in the email? I don't have access to the notification settings so I can't do anything there to modify the email content/body. My task is a bash@3 with inline script

Thanks in advance

Comment: this has virtually nothing to do with bash tag

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in task or feature in Azure Pipelines can send the output of tasks as an email notification.

However, from the [**Marketplace**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sent%20email&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance) of Azure DevOps, you can find some extensions that provide the pipeline tasks to send email.

> **Note:** Almost all the send email tasks need you provide the settings of a SMTP server. That means you need to configure a SMTP server for use on the send email tasks.

---

For your case, below is an example as reference:

```yaml
steps:
# Get the HTTP Status and set it as a pipeline variable.
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Get HTTP Status'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      http_status1=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" URL)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HTTP_STATUS1;]$http_status1"

# Send the HTTP Status via email.
- task: SendEmail@1
  displayName: 'Send HTTP Status'
  inputs:
    To: '{email addresses to receive the message}'
    From: '{email address to send the message}'
    Subject: 'HTTP Status'
    Body: |
     Successfully get the HTTP Status.
     The HTTP Status is: $(HTTP_STATUS1).
    SmtpServer: '$(Mail.Server)'
    SmtpPort: '$(Mail.Port)'
    SmtpUsername: '$(Mail.Username)'
    SmtpPassword: '$(Mail.Password)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately we can't use an SMTP server on my project. Sorry that's something I should've mentioned. I'll check keep looking on the marketplace for some extensions that might not need SMTP.

Comment: @eliew, You're welcome. So far, using the send email task in pipeline could be the only available method for your use case I can think of. Sure, you can take further search on the marketplace to see whether there is any extension that does not need you provide a SMTP Server configuration.